# Today extensions(Widget) can't show on iPhone5s

Tags: ios, widget, ios-app-extension, today-extension

My app contains a Today Extensions(Widget), but it can not show on iPhone5s, and any other devices can show normally.
Platform: xcode6 Beta5, iOS Beta5.

Comment: If you've already tried skrew's suggestion, try rebooting the device. Today widgets are still a little flaky.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add arm64 support for your today extension. iPhone 5S have a 64 bits processor and host application